# Where to put static files for Spark Web Framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spark-java

Where do I put files when trying to serve static files with the Spark web framework?

I haven't been able to find anything online - I'm beginning to suspect I don't understand anything about class paths, relative paths etc. for an Eclipse and Java project.

[This paragraph](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files) about static files in Spark refers to `/public`, but I have no idea where that would be. Using windows, Eclipse Luna and my project is converted to use Maven.

I've tried looking at the code on GitHub, but I'm a little out of my depth trying to find it.

Answer (score 55):

First you have to tell Spark where to search for the static files like this:

```
Spark.staticFiles.location("/public");
```

In Spark versions prior to 2.5, you should use:

```
Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");
```

Then your project should have a `public` folder under the resources folder like this

`/src/main/resources/public/style.css`

For example I added a `style.css` file there, so you should then access it like this:

`http://localhost:4567/style.css`

---

If you want to serve a non-classpath folder, then you should use

```
Spark.staticFiles.externalLocation("/path/to/dir");
```

In Spark versions prior to 2.5, you should use:

```
Spark.externalStaticFileLocation("/path/to/dir");
```

Comment: @JigarJoshi what issue are you talking about? Does my solution not work for you?

Comment: I ran into decision quickly, I was trying to set proper mime type for static resources I serve, I ended up using a Filter to set proper mime type for certain static resources

Comment: @JigarJoshi well if you serve the static files using `staticFileLocation` then you dont have to do that. If you serve the files manually registering a get with `Spark.get` then yes, you will have to set the headers manually.

Comment: I was serving css file using staticFileLocation and the mime type was not set properly

Comment: @JigarJoshi maybe you were using an old version of Spark? I never heard of anyone having that problem :/

Comment: I am using 2.3 which is [latest](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sparkjava/spark-core/) as of now I believe

Comment: where should I place the user uploaded image，it's the same as the src/main/resources?

Comment: @L.YanJun what are you talking about? This question is about serving static files, not user's files.

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez When I use `get("/post/:postId", (req, res) ->{...})`, the static file path become such like `http://0.0.0.0:4567/post/css/style.css`, but the correct path should be `http://0.0.0.0:4567/css/style.css`.

Comment: What if I want to serve my entire repository, not just the public folder?
I've tried `staticFiles.location(repoPath)` but it is not getting picked up? Does it only work with `public` folder? How can I access any file I want in the current directory?

Comment: No, the `public` folder is an example. The folder has to be in the classpath. If you want to use a non-classpath, then you can use `staticFiles.externalLocation`. I updated the anser with this.

Comment: The problem is the assets links in the HTML/template files will be broken. I like to design my pages as I go and do not want to go back in the template files to change the CSS/JS file links. Spark breaks the paths and I don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

I put my style sheets below my static content as follows:

```
staticFileLocation( "/web" );
/web/
  |-- index.html
  +-- styles/
        +
        +--- default.css
```

And the index.html

```
... <link href="styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" />
```

I also have other generated HTML pages as with freemarker.  They just collect the path:

- /styles/default.css,  or
- localhost:8081/styles/default.css

Shows the CSS way index gets it.

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sparkjava/5vMuK_5GEBU/vh_jHra75u0J

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click your project on Eclipse, select create New -> Package. Give the new package a name, etc.
2. Put your static resources under that package, so we can be sure they're under your classpath.
3. In your Main class colde, call staticFileLocation("yourpackagename/");

Answer (score 1):

1. Place your public directory into `src/main/resources`
2. Replace `Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");` to `Spark.staticFileLocation("public");`