# Mapping External Static Resources in Spark Framework(java)

Tags: spark-java

I'm very new to Spark. Will anyone please tell me how can I map external static resources? I am aware of the below method gotten from [here](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/com/sparkjava/spark-core/1.0&path=/Source%20Packages/spark/Spark.java) :

```
public static synchronized void externalStaticFileLocation(String  
   externalFolder) {

 if (initialized) {
         throwBeforeRouteMappingException();
    }
     externalStaticFileFolder = externalFolder;
}
```

But I do not know how to use it. I called it before Routing like

```
externalStaticFileLocation("/resources/*");
```

I also tried

```
staticFileLocation("css/CrudTemp.css");
staticFileLocation("js/jquery.js");
staticFileLocation("js/jquery-ui.js");
```

Also tried

```
Spark.staticFileLocation("src/main/resources/css");
Spark.staticFileLocation("src/main/resources/js");
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125886/where-to-put-static-files-for-spark-web-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by Creating public folder under src/main/resources
and then mapped it like

```
staticFileLocation("/public");
```

and then in template file i access that resources like

```
css/file.css
js/file.js
```

and it worked...
but still i do not know why it did not worked for above methods described in questions

Comment: depending on your environment, you may need to add the resulting jar of your application to the classpath