# Running html files in maven spark java application

Tags: javascript, java, html, maven, spark-java

I am working on a full-stack assignment. I have developed my backend REST Apis using spark java and maven. Now I am clueless about how to code the html and js files contacting the REST apis so as to develop a full stack application

I tried placing sample htmls under the root of the app and also under

```
src/main/resources/public/index.html
```

But it throws

```
404 not found
```

I have seen tutorials relating to spark java application with angular js https://blog.openshift.com/developing-single-page-web-applications-using-java-8-spark-mongodb-and-angularjs but I neither know Angular JS.

So can someone help me in understanding or guiding me to a resource on how to run html/js/css files with spark java application?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125886/where-to-put-static-files-for-spark-web-framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the static files should be found. An example is:

```
Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");
```

This public is a directory in your classpath called `public`. If you are using Maven, then this translates to

```
src/main/resources/public/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your **/public** folder path from your code. For example, you have your app structure as:

*YourNiceAppFolder/Server.jar*

*YourNiceAppFolder/public*

Just find your Server.jar file location and return path to /public folder. In this case, you shouldn't worry about building process(only about the relation between server.jar and public folder).

[image]
See example [here](https://github.com/andrewhrytsiv/dataset-manager/blob/heroku/src/main/java/com/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java)